# jq filtering output not matching multiple condition

Tags: filter, jq, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to filter the Cloudwatch output so that it only displays CPUUtilization threshold not equals to 70, 60 and 40.

The following filter works as expected, but I wonder if the `select(.Threshold)` command can be combined, or by using other operators/command.

```
jq '.MetricAlarms[]|select(.MetricName == "CPUUtilization")|select(.Threshold != 70)|select(.Threshold != 60)|select(.Threshold != 40)' alarms.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `jq` version supports [`IN` builtin](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in), using which you can check for your variable equals to multiple values and use `not` to negate it, you can do

```
.MetricAlarms[] 
| select( .MetricName == "CPUUtilization" and (.Threshold |  IN(40,60,70) | not ) )
```